# How to isolate the integration Tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

When having a database operations in many integration Tests, how to be sure that the state of the DataBase is the same before and after any Test in an automatic manner (with some framework) ?

I am not interested in the manual manner (`@Before` `@After`)

Comment: You can set transaction commit to false.

Comment: It could ignore some database constraint

Comment: Can you use the `@Sql` annotation? Write a sql script that recreates the state of the database and that annotation will execute it before every test, so you will have the same state for every test.

Answer (score 0):

What we do at my company is that

1. We use transactions to ensure that the DB is in the same state after the test as beforehand.
2. We use test scripts that ensure valid test data (e.g., inserting some additional rows to some tables for specific test scenarios, whereas updating some others). You can execute these scriptes in setUp methods to reuse them by multiple test cases or even define them in utility classes that can be reused by multple test suites.

This works finy in many scenarios, however, it may be problematic if you try to test parts of your application that are working with nested transactions.

Comment: This is usefull, I do the same but complete clean with a TestExecutionListener that executes before each test, cleans all tables and reset sequences. But that constrain the test to be sequencial and I'm start thinking on ways to refact the code to be parallel